# Flutter override Back Button for multiple willPops

Tags: flutter

in simple flutter you suppose i have 3 dialog for example:

```
return showGetnameDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        ...
      ),
    ) ?? false;

return showGetFamilyDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        ...
      ),
    ) ?? false;

return showGetAgeDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        ...
      ),
    ) ?? false;
```

and now `WillPopScope` only get has one `onWillPop` parameter for example

`_onWillPop,: _onWillPop,`

how can i manage this multiple `willPops` to override back button? for example:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) :super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

    Future<bool> _onNameWillPop() {
        return showGetnameDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            ...
          ),
        ) ?? false;
    }

    Future<bool> _onFamilyWillPop() {
        return showGetFamilyDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            ...
          ),
        ) ?? false;
    }

    Future<bool> _onAgeWillPop() {
        return showGetAgeDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            ...
          ),
        ) ?? false;
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onNameWillPop(), /*_onFamilyWillPop(), _onAgeWillPop*/
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to execute all 3 alert functions onWillPop?

Comment: @fayeed not in same time to show all dialogs, but i want to use them Which should be show and hide

Comment: What do you actually want to do? It seems like you simply want to prevent the user from closing your dialogs, is this correct?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot no, i'm using [overlay_support](https://github.com/boyan01/overlay_support) to show dialog on application, but it doesn't support back button pressed and i have to find to implementing that [reference](https://github.com/boyan01/overlay_support/issues/14)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
       Navigator.pop(context, false);
      }
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: after press back button, that cause of show multiple dialogs over each other

Comment: do you want to show a different dialog in turn like once back is pressed show dialog 1, second time shows the second dialog...?

Comment: after show dialog one and press back button i want to show dialog two and then can be use press back button, show once dialogs as separated times

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/ej1Ntyv1G5UYRHiNfU/giphy.gif) .

Comment: you suppose i have 3 button as `get name`,`get family`,`get age`, user can  press on each button as herself need and press back button to close opened dialog